# Can Avro schema have unknown / dynamic field names?

Tags: avro

Consider the following json:

```json
{
  "id": "5ffhj4ksWRyt",
  "name": "some name",
  "custom_fields": [
    "randomFieldName1": "a",
    "randomFieldName2": "b"
  ]
```

`id` and `name` fields are always known, but `custom_fields` names are dynamic and can have any key name. Is it possible to write a schema that will take that into account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `custom_fields` as a `map`

https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Maps

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. It seems that the `values` supported are only simple types like `string` or `long` ? I tried adding a union of `["string", "array"]` but it threw an error

Comment: I haven't really tried, but I believe Record values are supported if you could wrap a nullable string/array in a single type